# How to install a Tcl package?

Tags: package-management, installation-package, tcl

I am trying to run a Tcl script that has `package require cmdline`, and it complains:

> can't find package cmdline

How do I find and install another Tcl package into an existing Tcl installation?

Answer (score 6):

Check this page: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl31.html

Basically, to know where `tcl` looks, start a `tclsh`:

```
% puts $tcl_pkgPath
/usr/lib64 /usr/lib 
% puts $auto_path
/usr/lib64/tcl8.6 /usr/lib64 /usr/lib
```

but note that you will also need to generate (or install, if you already have it) a `pkgIndex.tcl` (the same reference above tells you how to make one).

Answer (score 4):

In CentOS, I just installed tcllib packages

```
sudo yum install tcllib
```