# How to install cmdline on Oracle Linux server

Tags: installation, package-management, installation-package, tcl

I am running into error `"package require cmdline"` while making a build and need this package, how can I install this package?

I Looked at [How to install a Tcl package?](https://superuser.com/questions/904021/how-to-install-a-tcl-package#) which doesnt exactly tell how to do that

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341141/package-for-parsing-argument-in-tcl and http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html to see if that gets you going in the right direction to help you resolve. If not, look over these answers and comments within https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=package+require+cmdline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- download the source from https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/
- install it into your home directory:

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=$HOME/tcl
  make install
  ```
- when you want to use one of the tcllib packages:

  ```
  set auto_path [linsert $auto_path 0 $env(HOME)/tcl/lib]
  package require cmdline
  ```

Comment: Is there a command line way to download the source from https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/,am using Oracle linux server and looking for a command line way?please advise

Comment: Did you try `yum install tcllib`? (I don't know what package manager that distro uses)

Comment: I tried but get the error `Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
public_ol6_UEKR3_latest                                                                                                                                                          | 1.2 kB     00:00     
public_ol6_latest                                                                                                                                                                | 1.4 kB     00:00     
No package tcllib available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: So, tcllib is not available in your package repositories. Install it manually

Comment: Oh, wait, a command line way to download the sources? Sure, copy the  download link from core.tcl.tk and use `curl` or `wget` to download it.

Comment: you mean something like `wget https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/wiki?name=Downloads`

Comment: I downloaded as `wget https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/uv/tcllib-1.19.zip`

Comment: and then tried `sudo yum install tcllib-1.19.zip`,still get the same error `No package tcllib-1.19.zip available`

Comment: You need to unzip and read the INSTALL file, where you will find instructions like I wrote in my answer.